# How to properly move function from component.ts to a service file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wrote a function in my component.ts which sends PUT request. It works as it should, but I want to move the function to a service.ts file. I moved it but it doesn't work. When I click "Save", it shows an error in console:

> FormsComponent.html:32 ERROR TypeError: _co.editForm is not a function
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (FormsComponent.html:32)
>       at handleEvent (core.js:23008)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24078)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23805)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.js:20457)
>       at core.js:20904
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.js:993)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17279)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:422) View_FormsComponent_0 @ FormsComponent.html:32
>   proxyClass @ compiler.js:18234
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError
>   @ core.js:24040
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError
>   @ core.js:15761 dispatchEvent @ core.js:20461 (anonymous) @
>   core.js:20904 (anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:993
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:423 onInvokeTask @ core.js:17279
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:422 push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @
>   zone.js:195
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:498 invokeTask @ zone.js:1744 globalZoneAwareCallback @
>   zone.js:1770 FormsComponent.html:32 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view:
>   {…}, nodeIndex: 31, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}

Here is my forms.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormService } from './forms.service';
import { form } from './form-interface';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})


export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {

  formsUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  id: any;
  form: form = {
    id: 0,
    userId: 0,
    title: '',
    body: ''
  };

  constructor(private formService: FormService ,private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id=this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.formService.getForms(this.id).subscribe(
      (forms: any) => {
        this.form = forms[0];
        console.log(this.form);
      }
    );

  }

  deleteForm() {
    this.http.delete(this.formsUrl + "/" + this.form.id)
    .subscribe(
      data  => {
      console.log("DELETE Request is successful ", data);
      },
      error  => {
      console.log("Error", error);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

here is my forms.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { form } from './form-interface';



@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
}) 

export class FormService {

formsUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
form: form = {
    id: 0,
    userId: 0,
    title: '',
    body: ''
  };


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getForms(id) {
        return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
        + "?id=" + id)
      }

      editForm() {
        fetch(this.formsUrl + "/" + this.form.id, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify(this.form),
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
      }


}
```

And here is my HTML file:

```
<div class="forms container">
  <form #postForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="form.title"
          name="title"  
          id="title" 
          type="text" 
          class="form-control"
          >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="form.body" 
        name= "body" 
        id="body" 
        cols="30" 
        rows="10" 
        class="form-control"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click) = editForm()>Save</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" (click) = deleteForm()>Delete</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `(click) = editForm()` in you template just executes `this.editForm` function from your component. Your component doesn't have this function, but the service has it. So, you have to do this `(click) = formService.editForm()` but `formService` has to be public. Or you can create a function in your component `editForm() {this.formService.editForm()}`.

Comment: @Lends It doesn't work. I changed the code in that way but it gives me another error: PUT https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/0 500
core.js:15713 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Comment: actually it works. Yout component executes a function from your service. Now your request has an error. Why do you use fetch when you have HttpClient?

Comment: Oh, and as I see you have a problem with keeping `form` value. You have one form in service and one form in a component. It's would be better if you would remove everything about form in your component and just keep all logic and data in `formService`. And just trigger `formService` methods in your component.

Comment: @Lends It actually works!
God bless you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it clean and tidy you can do something like this:

```
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {
  form = this.formService.form;

  constructor(private formService: FormService, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.formService.loadFormsById(this.id)
        .subscribe(([form]) => this.formService.updateForm(form));
  }

  saveForm() {
    this.formService.saveForm();
  }

  deleteForm() {
    this.formService.deleteForm();
  }

}
```

And Service:

```
export class FormService {

    formsUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    form: form = {
       id: 0,
       userId: 0,
       title: '',
       body: ''
    };


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    loadFormsById(id) {
       // load your form here
    }

    updateForm(form) {
       // update your form here
    }

    saveForm() {
       // save your form here
    }

    deleteForm() {
       // delete your form here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `editForm()` in the template as it is not existing in your component. If you want to call that function from the service, use `formService.editForm()` instead

But in that case, you need to make `formService` public, so use `public formService: FormService` instead of `private formService: FormService`.

You can also clone that function in the component so you don't need to change the template and make the service public, as `public editForm = formService.editForm`

or

```
editForm() {
     return this.formService.editForm();
}
```

Comment: I changed the code in that way but it gives me another error: PUT jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/0 500 core.js:15713 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Comment: that is the different issue, as I understand the JSON you get is not correct, could you post it here?

Comment: the response.json() could be the cause of that error message

Answer (score 0):

seems that parse error. try fix error in html:

put (click) = "editForm()"  and (click) = "deleteForm()"

```
<div class="forms container">
  <form #postForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="form.title"
          name="title"  
          id="title" 
          type="text" 
          class="form-control"
          >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="form.body" 
        name= "body" 
        id="body" 
        cols="30" 
        rows="10" 
        class="form-control"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click) = "editForm()">Save</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" (click) = "deleteForm()">Delete</button>
  </form>
</div>
```